# directly segueing between different detail view controllers

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have an iPhone master-detail storyboard app which uses two differ detail view Controllers (a create VC and an edit VC).  From the master view, if I hit the "+" new button I segue programmatically to the create VC while if I choose a tableViewCell the program segues to the edit VC.  All that is working just peachy.  Now I want to be able to segue directly from the create VC to the edit VC.  Problem is I end up with the exception 'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'

My storyboard looks like this.
[image: Storyboard]

I've also tried embedding my detail VCs in navigation VCs without success.

Also, keep in mind that I'm trying to go from a stack of 
master->createDetail
directly to
master->editDetail
not
master->createDetail->editDetail.
I really just want to pop off the createDetail and replace it with an editDetail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Suppose there are 2 parameters to send on next view as CustomerName and Email then code will be : 

-(IBAction)btnNextViewClicked:(id)sender 
{ 
UIStoryboard * myStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];

NextViewController * nextView = [myStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"nextViewCNTR"];
nextView.validEmail = @"abc@gmail.com";
nextView.customerName = @"ABC";

[self.navigationController nextView animated:YES]; 
}
```

If U dont have parameter then :

```
-(IBAction)btnNextViewClicked:(id)sender 
{ 
UIStoryboard * myStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];

NextViewController * nextView = [myStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"nextViewCNTR"];

[self.navigationController nextView animated:YES]; 
}
```

nextViewCNTR is name of indentifier to put on flow line while desingning in XCode.

Use and let me know feedback.

Comment: When you say [self.navigationController nextView animated:YES]; do you mean [self.navigationController popToViewController:nextVC animated:YES];? I followed your code and change the in the IB Identity inspector I set the viewContoller's Storyboard ID to match the instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier method, but I get this error _* Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Tried to pop to a view controller that doesn't exist.'_

Comment: @honkskillet : Don't use [self.navigationController popToViewController:nextVC animated:YES]; 

Use only this while seguing between views [self.navigationController nextView animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

use a UIContainerView in your detailview

Comment: What does that achieve?

Comment: if you put a container view in your detailview you can add segue's to your view in de container and have what you want